# Are exosomes useful as a transfection or delivery mechanism in gene editing?

Tags: genetics, cell-biology, virology, crispr, cas9

The use of viruses as transfection or delivery agents for gene editing (CRISPR/cas9, etc) is well known. However, one problem with using viruses to deliver DNA into cells is the possibility of triggering an adverse immune response.

Cells already use exosomes to transport various cargo in and out of cells. Does this characteristic make exosomes ideal candidates for delivering gene editing cargo as well?

Also, are there any known examples or studies involving repurposing exosomes for gene editing? Specifically for CRISPER/cas9 applications?